# Why does my "if" statement seem to ignore itself, it runs it's code, but not conditionally?

Tags: python, python-2.7

***Disclaimer: I am still very new to Python, so if there is an obvious thing that I am missing I apologize, but I couldn't figure it out on my own...***

So this is the code I'm working with:

```
def typeFunct():
  userType= str(raw_input())
  print(userType)
typeFunct()

def main():
  userYn = input("do you wish to type something? (y/n)")
  if (userYn == "y" or "Y"):
    typeFunct()
  if(userYn == "n" or "N"):
    print(" ")
main()
```

So basically I am working with some code and am trying to use a programmer-created function in order to prompt the user into inputting text that is then printed on the screen, however before I use said function, I am first prompting the user as to whether or not they actually want to type anything with a simple "y/n" input that triggers an `if` statement:

```
userYn = input("do you wish to type something? (y/n)")
  if (userYn == "y" or "Y"):
    typeFunct()
  if(userYn == "n" or "N"):
    print(" ")
```

However though testing I found that the code doesn't seem to actually care if the condition of y/n is true or not, it runs both regardless of the condition given, I also tried using an `else:` statement:

```
  else:
    print(" ")
```

but still no dice, is there like a glaring error in my programming that I am missing that is making `if` statements act like this?

Comment: Print out `userYn == "y" or "Y"`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think string expressions just evaluate to true. You should try this:

```
if (userYn == "y" or userYn == "Y"):
  typeFunct()
if(userYn == "n" or userYn == "N"):
  print(" ")
```

With `if (userYn == "y" or "Y")`, you aren't checking if `userYn is` is `"y"` or `"Y"`, you are checking if `userYn` is equal to `"y"`, then checking if the expression after the `or` evaluates to true, then if any one of them is true, running the code. It's running unconditionally because I think string literals always evaluate to true.